# How to clean the URL coming from database in PHP?

Tags: php, image, url

I've an URL that is coming from the database as follows.

```
http://34.158.85.145/file/pic/user/2014/11/d424bc46529b9f8d764b6b485e6c8716%s.png
```

Now if you closely look at the image name some special symbols are getting inserted in it's name. I want to avoid it so I wrote following logic for it but it didn't work.

```
$user_image = Slug('http://34.158.85.145/file/pic/user/2014/11/d424bc46529b9f8d764b6b485e6c8716%s.png');

function Slug($string) {
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
  }
```

Can someone please help me in cleaning up this image name in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should the filename be, all I can see added is a '%s'  onto the end of the filename, which isn't something I'd expect to see added onto a filename. Its more like a format specifier that's not been passed to sprintf()

Comment: I think your main problem is to prevent those names from being inserted in db in first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove all special chars (except '.') from the filename of a URL you could simply use something like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://34.158.85.145/file/pic/user/2014/11/d424bc46529b9f8d764b6b485e6c8716%s.png';
$exp= explode('/', $url);
$image = array_pop($exp);
$replace = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9.\-]/', '', $image);
$url = str_replace($image, $replace, $url);
var_dump($url);
```